# Software Updater keeps suggesting to upgrade, after the upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, 21.04

On a new laptop shipped with Ubuntu 20.04, I changed the `Software & Updates` options to get notified about new versions of Ubuntu.  Then when I ran `Software Updater`, it suggested to upgrade to 21.04.  Which I did.  All seemed fine.

But since then, every time I run `Software Updater`, it keeps asking me to upgrade:

[image: software updater ask to upgrade]

If I ask to upgrade again, the process starts:

[image: welcome to hirsute]

At first, all seems fine:

[image: seems ok]

But it feels, apparently during "Setting new software channels":

[image: eventually fails]

This last one shows for around one second, before disappearing, with no other message whatsoever.  Any odea what could be wrong?  How could I get more info about why the updater crashes?

[EDIT]

During the first upgrade, everything seemed fine, and I thought the upgrade was successful.  But `lsb_release` still mentions 20.04.  Altough `apt update` uses `hirsute` repositories.  It looks like my system is in some kind of in-between state:

```
me@mine:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-stantler X80)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

me@mine:~$ sudo apt update 
[sudo] password for fgeorges: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB]                          
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB]                        
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                     
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]                        
Fetched 310 kB in 1s (331 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

me@mine:~$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

me@mine:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: So you actually didn't release upgrade because the upgrader failed. Unsurprisingly it keeps suggesting it. The real question here is indeed *why* it failed, not what's in the title. Before trying again make sure your system is fully updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Check for errors. Very likely you can't do a direct upgrade because you'd need to go from 20.04 to 20.10 to 21.04 and 20.10 is EoL already.

Comment: Thank you, @ChanganAuto!  I thought the (first) upgrade was successful, but indeed `lsb_release` keeps saying `focal`.  But `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade` report nothing wrong (and `update` seems to use `hirsute` repos.)  I edited my question and added more info at the end.  I am lost now (more than 1 hour ago :-P)

Comment: I started previous comment with general advice. The problem is you can't skip releases and 20.10 is out of support, you missed the upgrade window by a few months.

Comment: Argh, I thought that if it was suggested by the updater, it was supported :-(((